# How can I set up a Pusher server with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, websocket, pusher

I am trying to setup a simple `flask` server:

```
import envkey
import pysher
from flask import Flask
# from predictor import PythonPredictor
app = Flask(__name__)


pusher = pysher.Pusher(envkey.get('PUSHER_KEY'))


def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
    print("processing Args:", args)
    print("processing Kwargs:", kwargs)

# We can't subscribe until we've connected, so we use a callback handler
# to subscribe when able


def connect_handler(data):
    print('connect habndler')
    channel = pusher.subscribe('mychannel')
    channel.bind('myevent', my_func)


pusher.connection.bind('pusher:connection_established', connect_handler)


@app.route('/')
def index():

    pusher.connect()

    return 'Server Works!'
```

But I Get an error:

```
RuntimeError: cannot join current thread
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like there is already a running process and which is not killed.... can you verify that with `ps -aux`  command and kill the process if its already running?

Comment: At which point the error occurs? Whe'n you start your Flask server or when you poke that endpoint with `pusher.connect()` statement?

Comment: The .connect is where it fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying my Pusher cluster during initalization helped me get rid of that issue:

```
pusher = pysher.Pusher(
    key=envkey.get('PUSHER_KEY'),  # Or however you get the key
    cluster="eu",  # Add cluster!
)
```